# How to fix Paypal error 10001 Internal error

Tags: paypal

I am using custom code for payment in wordpress where i am facing same error

Internal error - 10001 in sandbox account.

See given error array:

```
[reshash] => Array (
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2013-09-16T05:43:07Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 76e0b30fbaab6
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 65.1
    [BUILD] => 7729086
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10001
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Internal Error
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Internal Error
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
    [L_ERRORPARAMID0] => ProcessorResponse
    [L_ERRORPARAMVALUE0] => 0000
    [AMT] => 1.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [AVSCODE] => X
    [CVV2MATCH] => M
)
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

IF you are making do direct method for payment and making payment then 
**Add IP address** in code. that solved issue for me
for e.g

```
  $payment->setIpAddress('127.0.0.1');
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I am using the PayPal NVP APIs and performing a parallel payment via express checkout and using auth/capture.

I know this question is old, but setting the IP address to 127.0.0.1 did not fix the error for me.  To execute the payment without getting internal errors, follow this guideline:

During method `SetExpressCheckout`, set all PAYMENTREQUEST_n_PAYMENTACTION fields to "order", and when using method `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`, set all PAYMENTREQUEST_n_PAYMENTACTION fields to "sale".

Examples:

```
// Create the order and receive your TOKEN
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=order

// { redirect to paypal for user authorization }

// Capture the payment (execute payment and finalize sale)
METHOD=DoExpressCheckoutPayment&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=sale
```

You can read more information about the SetExpressCheckout method in the [PayPal API docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/). When I compared the SetExpressCheckout docs with those for DoExpressCheckoutPayment, I did not see any requirement for changing the payment action to sale.  Not really sure why it worked, and I really wish their error messages were more descriptive.